# E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout NEW

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have looked at many solutions and have made adjustments based on feedback from a previous version of the code I had but i still cant seem to get it to work and have the same error

JudgeActivty:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_judge);

    RecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    ProgressCircle = findViewById(R.id.progress_circle);

    mUploads = new ArrayList<>();

    DatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");

    DatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                UploadClass upload =
                        postSnapshot.getValue(UploadClass.class);
                mUploads.add(upload);
            }
            Adapter = new ImageAdapter(JudgeActivity.this, mUploads);
            ProgressCircle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            RecyclerView.setAdapter(Adapter);
        }
    });
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends
        RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ImageViewHolder> {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<UploadClass> mUploads;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, List<UploadClass> uploads) {
        mContext = context;
        mUploads = uploads;
    }


    @Override
    public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.image_item,
                parent, false);
        return new ImageViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {
        UploadClass uploadCurrent = mUploads.get(position);
        holder.textViewName.setText(uploadCurrent.getName());
        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(uploadCurrent.getImageUrl())
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .fit()
                .centerCrop()
                .into(holder.imageView);

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mUploads.size();
    }

    public class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView textViewName;
        public ImageView imageView;

        public ImageViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_name);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view_upload);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: please show your code

Answer (score 0):

Is there actually a problem? That "error" isn't an error, it's just a warning. And it's shown because, when the Activity is first displayed, the RecyclerView has no Adapter set to it. You only set the Adapter when a Firebase value changes, which is a bad idea.

You should create and set the Adapter outside of the ValueEventListener:

```
RecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
Adapter = new ImageAdapter(JudgeActivity.this, mUploads);
RecyclerView.setAdapter(Adapter);
```

Also, in Java, variable names follow `camelCase`, not `TitleCase`. You don't have to follow that guideline, but it makes it less confusing for others when debugging your code.

Comment: The issue is the images that are supposed to be displayed aren't displaying but maybe this is due to something else?

Comment: @A.Fitzgerald it likely is. A ValueEventListener listens for changes in the current DB reference. It doesn't do an initial retrieval of the current values.